# Restoring database from uninstalled WAMP server

Tags: backup, mysql, wamp

I have uninstalled WAMP server by mistake without creating a backup of my database, but I have a copy of the data folder C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data.

I have reinstalled WAMP and configured it. WAMP is working fine but after I copied the data folder to the new installation, MYSQL service is not starting.

MYSQL Log

> 130708 16:40:56 [ERROR] Binlog has bad magic number;  It's not a binary log file that can be used by this version of MySQL
>
> 130708 16:40:56 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
>
> 130708 16:40:56 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 130708 16:40:56  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 130708 16:40:56  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 4542425

How can I restore my database?

Comment: Hey Figured out a solution for this

in path: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data 

find mysql-bin.index file rename that with mysql-bin.index-corrupt 

restart server it will work fine and you have all your database where you left them

CHEERS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this:

1. Go to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data
2. Find a file called "mysql-bin.index"
3. Rename that file to "mysql-bin.index-corrupt"

Restart the server and it will work fine, all your database will be where you left them.